# Api de criação de usuário está retornando Status 204 No Content

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Estou desenvolvendo uma api que eu pego o `id` do usuário da requisição através do `token`, guardo no meu objeto de usuário e realizo o cadastro desse usuário. O problema é que não está retornando nada, mesmo eu colocando return user. Se eu colocar um `console.log(user)` antes do `return` meu objeto está conforme o esperado (informações do usuário que foi cadastrado + token, porém a api retorna Status 204 + No content.

Eu tentei:

```
const User = use("App/Models/User")

class UserController {

    store ({ request, auth }){

        let user = request.all()

        this.usuarioLogado(auth).then(async res => { 
            user.user_id = res.id
            user = await User.create(user)
            const token = await auth.generate(user)
            Object.assign(user, token)
            return user
        })
    }

    async usuarioLogado(auth) {
        try {
            return await auth.getUser()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `return this.usuarioLogado(auth).then...`?

Comment: não, eu tentei dessa forma. eu tive que atribuir o retorno do user a uma constante, e depois retornar essa constante.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho o `Adonis` em minha máquina para simular este teste. Mas lendo, parece ser somente algo relacionado ao Javascript. Eu não sei o que a sua variável `token` esta retornando. Mas, vamos supor que ela tenha um valor retornado como:

```
const token = { value: 'asdo12398j129e12v9ne9182u2098343847230m4m03' };
```

E vamos supor também que `user` tenha a seguinte saída:

```
const user = {
    name: 'Thiago'
};
```

Ou seja, retornando um objeto... Logo, isso faz sentido ter a função `Object.assign`...

A saída seria...

```
{
  name: 'Thiago',
  value: 'asdo12398j129e12v9ne9182u2098343847230m4m03'
}
```

Isso é o mesmo que `user.value = token.value`.

Tente explorar a seguinte saída: `{user, token}`... a saída faria mais sentido, pois token não é filho de `user` (acredito), e sim um objeto que somente tem um relacionamento em comum com 'user'.

Veja a saida também de Token para saber se esta sendo impresso também. Isso é importante para eu atualizar essa questão... pois não sei o comportamento do valor de toke, bem como a sua estrutura vindo da consulta.

Use o objeto `Response` do Adonis para retornar o resultado. Ele já contém uma estrutura bacana para retornar o que você precisa, bem como trabalhar o Status das saídas.